# Unity AI.Navigation NaveMeshSurface.BuildNavMesh() produces bad results

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I am using the AI.Navigation system on the following scene :
[before play mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV0I6.png)

Since it's a scene with element which will be deleted dynamically, I'm not baking the scene beforehand but call once
Floor.GetComponent().BuildNavMesh();

"Floor", beeing the game object holding the NavMeshSuface component.
The first call does a pretty good job (Except for some reason it exclude the player with the NavMeshAgent, although the player also has a NavMeshModifier component with remove, why ?).
[first call to BuildNavMesh() in Play mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8XnZ.png)

Then the next time Floor.GetComponent().BuildNavMesh(); gets called, is when the the game object on the left (the dumpster/garbage) is set to inactive. And then the results is completly wrong :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xj6K.png)

What am I not understanding, doing wrong ? I would like to be able to create a dynamic mesh at runtime which will adapt to active/inactive objects preset with NavMeshModifiers (add/remove). For example, if the dumpster blocks a path, setting it to inactive should "open the path".

I've followed all tutorials I could find, but still can't understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: if you got objects that come and go, why not just have the navmesh adjustements on them so they carve the holes as they appear/move/or go ...

Comment: Any link/tutorial on how it can be done ?

Comment: its not that hard and no i dont have links - google might, but, look at the navmesh components, look at what they do, it will stand out

Comment: Indeed, I managed to do everything I wanted with NavMeshModifier et NavMeshObstacle components. The problem was that I still was spoiled by the "old obsolete" Navigation approach. Thanks